# Pig udf efficiency against cascaded built in fucntions

Tags: apache-pig, pig-udf, bigdata

I am new to PIG scripting, I had a requirement where I needed to perform Ladder If Else for upto 10 conditions,
From what knowledge I have we only have ternary operator, so i was thinking to write a UDF, insted of cascading the ternary operator like below :-
( condition : statement1 ? ( condition : statement 2 ? statement 3 ))

The data size is in tens of million rows, Should i even proceed with putting an effort in creating a UDF for my requirement.?

As in the end if it causes performance problems there will be no point in putting an effort.

From what i know, a call to the UDF will be made for each row in consideration, and a recursive call on a Million records is a serious overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you have access for a big cluster the UDF should't be a problem and it's improve the readability of your script. 
At the end your script also compiled to a java executable.
The biggest win on the performance if you can filter your data before the expensive operations.

Comment: Thanks Kecso, I had done the same thing, removed unnecessary attributes of the data, and then did the complex logic, the code is performing a little better now.